# tcp server throws error when receiving data from client

Tags: c#, tcpserver

hi i am new to TCP listening application under c# i manage to make the server listen to a specific port but when the server is about to read the stream it throws `NullReferenceException` in this code

```
TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
```

when i run the application all is fine until the server starts to read data

i tried using this code

```
TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream;
        clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
```

but the error is the same

any help will do

thank you

Comment: What exception? where? post the actual exception name, message and stacktrace and line which throws the exception.

Comment: sorry for that the error is nullreference exception at this code NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

Comment: should i post the entire code? its not that long of a code

Comment: Refer the duplicate link right above your question. It will guide you what is `NullReferenceException` and some debugging help to fix it.